# Delete a file from BOOT-INF/lib

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

How to delete a file from BOOT-INF/lib folder of executable jar while building the executable jar?
I have tried using maven antrun plugin with delete tag.

```
<delete file="${project.basedir}/target/classes/xyz.jar/abc.whl " />
```

This one works fine. But when I use the below line, it doesn't work

```
<delete file="${project.basedir}/target/lib/xyz.jar/abc.whl " />
```

Comment: The library files probably won't be copied to some central place before building the executable jar, but referenced directly from wherever they lay (probably the maven local cache). It's almost certainly better to exclude the library from the jar build and not try to delete it after the fact.

Comment: Ya that's correct. But how to delete a specific file in a library?

Comment: I'm telling you not to try to delete it from the ready-built jar. Instead change the place where the jar file is built (presumably that has an option to add excludes, for example). If you need help with *that* then show us the place where the jar is built.

Comment: You could try to explicitely exclude the dependency.

Comment: @JijoAntony you have to unpack the jar file, then delete your wanted file physically. After that you have to recreate the jar file. The jar file uses the zip algorithm. Good luck.

Comment: The question is why is the file being added if you don't need/want it to be? Accidentally? You have to find the location where the file is being defined as dependency which you can removed (presumable not needed)?

Comment: What's involved in "_This one works fine._" and in "_it doesn't work_"? Is there any error message, i.e. build output? If yes, please add it to your question. What is the expected result of your tries? What is the actual results? Please add these to your question, too.